# Eclipse Android Project Error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm creating an Android Project using Eclipse. When I first open Eclipse an error shows under the console tab at the bottom of the screen:

"Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one."

I'm not quite sure what this means or how to do it. If there is any code I should add to the question in order to make it more clear let me know.
Any help is GREATLY appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: not sure why it's relevant that you're a high school student...

Comment: hahaha... +1 jondavidjohn. At least it was a funny title :) **EDIT** omfg, his last question also contains that description in the title http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250146/high-school-student-with-programming-error LMAO

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, the `default.properties` file looks like:

```
target=android-7
```

android-7 means that the target of your app is Android 2.1. You can use, for instance, android -4 if you want to target Android 1.6, or android-9 if you want to target Android 2.3, etc. Whatever you choose, you must have already downloaded the packages for that Android version.

Answer (score 0):

A default.properties file is usually created when you create an android project via the New-Wizard.

Just create a file default.properties and you are ready to go. It holds the "target" value.